# Coffeescript in html code

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to use CoffeeScript in the front-end part of my code. I've not been able to locate the precise location of the JavaScript script for running CoffeeScript on the front-end. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple issue to solve, and I believe it has already been posted on Stack Overflow. For your knowledge, however, it would be correct to view the documentation on CoffeeScript's website, specifically  [here](http://coffeescript.org/#scripts).

The URL to the compiler is [here](http://coffeescript.org/v1/browser-compiler/coffee-script.js).

Once you've added the script to this hyperlink, add this code and you're good!

```
<script type="text/coffeescript"> # Your code </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the URL to the script. I got the CoffeeScript working on the front-end!

Answer (score 0):

Usually people run node on local machine and node transpiles the coffeescript to javascript for you.

Comment: Inserting the coffeescript into a view isn't a good practice because it eventually has to be converted into javascript by the client machine. It's best to transpile into javascript before you deploy for public usage.

Comment: I only want to use it for quick development, but thank you!